# "Facto" e "fato" podem ser consideradas palavras homófonas?

Tags: etimologia, gramática, homofonia

"Facto" e "fato" podem ser consideradas palavras homófonas ?

palavras homófonas e homógrafas

Comment: Porque perguntas se podem ser consideradas homófonas? Achas que têm o mesmo som? E, o que queres dizer com a frase "palavras homófonas e homógrafas" que puseste no fim da pergunta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não, são parônimas (**parecidas**) mas não homófonas.

Homófonas têm o **som** exatamente igual: cerração e serração.

Fato e facto apresentam pronúncias distintas, o c de `facto` não é mudo, por isso não são consideradas homófonas.

Note que palavras que apresentam plural metafônico, ou pequenas variações fonéticas como pôde e póde (grafei o acento apenas para explicitar), não são homófonas, o critério para serem homófonas é ter a fonética exatamente igual.

Comment: Pois, numa lê-se o "C". Muitas pessoas dizem muito rápido que no som fica igual

Comment: Eu dei uma pesquisada sobre isso, no Brasil facto é bem raro, só se usa em expressões do latim: "de facto", mas a expressão "de fato" é mais usada. Em portugal usa-se a pronúncia fak·tu. Numa análise meramente lexical, são palavras distintas com pronúncias distintas, que remetem ao mesmo significado.

Comment: Em Portugal têm significados diferentes: fac·to |ct|
(latim factum, -i, aquilo que se fez, façanha, proeza, acto)

sub masculino
1. Coisa realizada. = ACTO, FEITO
2. Acontecimento.
3. Sucesso.
4. Assunto (de que se trata).
5. Lance.

fa·to
(origem duvidosa, talvez do árabe hatu, peixes, cardume)

sub. masculino
1. Conjunto das peças de roupa. = VESTUÁRIO
2. [Portugal]  Indumentária completa, geralmente do mesmo tecido, composto de casaco, colete e calças ou de casaco e calças.
3. [Portugal]  Conjunto de vestuário feminino formado por saia e casaco, geralmente do mesmo tecido.

Comment: Meu Houaiss direciona facto para fato.

Comment: Acho que deves pelo menos indicar na resposta poeque é que são diferentes: o "c" não é mudo. Talvez até ir mais longe e indicar que se o "c" for mudo, a escrita da palavra muda e o c desaparece; veja-se por exemplo em https://www.infopedia.pt/$facto-ou-fato

Comment: É um facto que sim